# google icon not loading on profile page in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, firebaseui

I used a pre-existing solution provided by Google Firebase for login in Flutter ( https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#0 ). There are two providers, Google and Mail. Both are working perfectly fine; all the buttons are working and functionalities are as well.

But the icon for Google is not being loaded on the profile screen; everywhere else, all the other icons are being loaded, even the Google icon is loaded on sign in screen, but it is being shown like this on the profile page -> ☒

The link to the photo for reference -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GBLxUxBRSYQSDd7SeiGsNoovVpZXHufv/view?usp=sharing

I cannot understand what to possibly try, I tried changing the version of Cupertino icons, but I doubt that is the issue since the first time I ran the code it showed the icon but never since then.
also since it is all built-in, I really do not have much to change in my code.

My code for profile screen:

```
onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute<ProfileScreen>(
              builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: const Text('User Profile'),
                ),
                actions: [
                  SignedOutAction((context) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  })
                ],
                children: [
                  const Divider(),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "A safe place for all.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24, // Adjust the font size as needed
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, // Add bold style
                        color: Colors.teal, // Change the text color
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    // Adjust the padding as needed
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1.5,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/3698931.jpg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
```